# Changing Slack CURL call into PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, curl, slack-api

I've in the middle of writing a translation of a working Slack script from Bash to Powershell, and I'm stumbled on what is literally the meat of the problem; how to use Invoke-WebRequest to replace curl.

This is the curl command that works successfully in Bash on *nix systems:

```
curl \
-X POST \
-H "Content-type: application/json" \
--data "{
   \"attachments\": 
   [
      {
         \"mrkdwn_in\": [\"text\"],
         \"color\": \"$COLOUR\",
         \"text\": \"$MESSAGE\",
      }
   ]
}" \
https://hooks.slack.com/services/tokenpart1/tokenpart2
```

Note the $COLOUR and $MESSAGE variables are derived from elsewhere in the script (not the section I'm having trouble with).

I can't get it to work in PowerShell. My translation so far is:

```
$Body = @{
   "attachments" = "[
      {
         "mrkdwn_in": ["text"],
         "color": "$Colour",
         "text": "$Message",

   ]"
}

$BodyJSON = $Body |convertto-JSON

Invoke-WebRequest -Headers -Method Post -Body "$BodyJSON" -Uri "https://hooks.slack.com/services/tokenpart1/tokenpart2" -ContentType application/json
```

This results in the following error:

```
At C:\path-to-file-etc.ps1:53 char:11
+          "mrkdwn_in": ["text"],
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'mrkdwn_in": ["text"],
         "color": "$COLOUR",
         "text": "$MESSAGE",
      }
   ]"' in expression or statement.
At C:\path-to-file-etc.ps1:53 char:11
+          "mrkdwn_in": ["text"],
+           ~
The hash literal was incomplete.At 
C:\path-to-file-etc.ps1:53 char:11
+          "mrkdwn_in": ["text"],
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx 
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Process exited with code 1
Process exited with code 1
Step Notify (PowerShell) failed
```

I have pretty much zero experience in Powershell. Also because this script has to be able to dropped onto a whole variety of boxes,**I won't use any libraries or custom cmdlets or anything like that.** Out of box methods or die.

Comment: This is a syntax error; you are missing a `}` before the `]` in your attachments.

Comment: I understand not wanting libraries but custom cmdlets are no different then scripted code... you could just add a function or some such thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) anyway, it's **simpler to construct the *entire* input as a (nested) custom object / hashtable, and let `ConvertTo-Json` handle all JSON formatting**:

```
$Body = [pscustomobject] @{
  attachments = , [pscustomobject] @{
    mrkdwn_in = , 'text'
    color = $Colour
    text = $Message
  }
}

$BodyJson = $Body | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3
```

<sup>Note: You could substitute `[ordered]` for `[pscustomobject]` to use a hashtable with ordered keys instead; even omitting either would work, though seeing the entries in the resulting JSON in different order may be confusing.</sup>

Note the use of `,`, the array-construction operator, to ensure that the `attachments` and `mrkdwn_in` entries are treated as arrays.

Additionally, since **`ConvertTo-Json` only fully serializes to a default depth of `2` levels**, `-Depth 3` must be used to ensure that the value of entry `mrkdwn_in` is serialized as an array.

---

As for **what you tried**:

Your ***immediate* problem** (in addition to the missing `}` that Jeff Zeitlin points out in a comment on the question): **You've neglected to *escape* the *embedded* `"` chars.** in your multi-line string.
Therefore, as documentation topic [`Get-Help about_Quoting_Rules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) discusses, you can either use `` `" `` to embed double quotes inside `"..."` or use a here-string (`@"<nl>....<n>"@`).

**Even with the syntax problems fixed, your code wouldn't work as intended**, however, because **`ConvertTo-Json` wouldn't preserve the *pre-formatted* JSON** in the `attachments` entry and instead treat the string value as a string *literal* that needs escaping; here's a simple example:

```
@{ 
    foo = "[
      1, 
      2 
    ]"
 } | ConvertTo-Json
```

The above yields:

```
{
  "foo": "[\n    1, \n    2 \n   ]"
}
```